# Barcode number checking with Excel

Tags: excel, numbers, excel-formula, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a problem to solve. I scanned 500 barcodes (barcode numbers Excel), which are placed in column A. Now I want to check if the barcode that a given customer returned to me is one of the 500 barcodes scanned before.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help.

Munix

Comment: There are dozens of ways to identify duplicates. Can you supply sample data and expected results? How do you want to identify the duplicates? What do you want to do with them once you've found them?

Comment: They are Bingo tables I don`t want people take them home and play with them next time, so I put barcodes on the back. I scan the tables I have, than the winning one this way I know is one of the "good one"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your barcode numbers are in A1:A19, and the barcode number you want to test is in B1, a formula for testing is

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$19,0))
```

There are quite a few other options.
Copy and paste as needed.

Comment: gives me an error "formula you typed contains an error"

Comment: It`s working now there was "," instead of ";" Thanks